# How to force GZIP for Development Google Appengine Server

Tags: google-app-engine, gzip, dev-appserver

My code can get gzip content from google appengine server, but it gets the full size from localhost (appengine dev server). It looks it using jetty as web server. Is it possible to force localhost to use gzip?

Comment: You mean in Headers ? Accept encoding ?

Comment: I mean server side. Chrome's network tools showing gzip works on remote gae server, but does not works on local gae development server

Comment: lots of stuff does not work locally. Deploy it and see what happens.

Comment: This is a long shot 6 years later, but did you ever get this figured out?